# ES6 Class method most efficient way to reference the class instance internally

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given the class below, how can i reference the instance of the class inside methods that return a promise for example?

Do i have to do `var self = this` inside every single method that returns a promise?

```
class Group {

  constructor() {}

  foo() {

    // 'this' references the class instance here
    console.log(this.myProp); => 'my value'

    // could do this 'var self = this' but do i need to add this code to every method that returns a promise?

    return Q.promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      // 'this' does NOT reference the class instance here
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this

Comment: You can do the `self` thing, or you can use `.bind()` to bind the callback functions to the context object. Or you can use arrow functions like SLaks says.

Comment: Ugh.  It should NOT work this way.  One should be able to refer to any instance variable (using 'this') anywhere within any method within the class.  I'm very disappointed.  It's a very leaky abstraction.  There should never be exceptions like this; either ensure that 'this' works everywhere or else go back to the drawing board and overhaul Javascript (again).

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need the promise's context, use arrow functions

```
class Group {

  constructor() {}

  foo() {

    // 'this' references the class instance here
    console.log(this.myProp); => 'my value'

    // could do this 'var self = this' but do i need to add this code to every method that returns a promise?

    return Q.promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // 'this' references the class instance here
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `this` inside a promise callback will be global/undefined in strict mode or module (in both native ES6 and also Q) anyway so arrow function is the correct way to go.

Comment: @RGraham now that I'm thinking about it I don't know that I've ever tried to use `this` in a promise callback. Good looking out!